# How to end task in batch?

Tags: batch-file, task, taskkill

How to end/stop a task/programm
in batch-files quickly ?

If it's possible to stop all programms with one command please say it to me.

I tried`taskkill firefox`
But it doesnt work

Thank you for answers ; )

Answer (score 1):

For Example,

```
TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe
```

You can replace the taskname `notepad.exe` with your process.

You can check running process from `Task manager » Process`

you can find the `Firefox` process name there, if it is running.

Comment: Thank you for you answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch file to kill a process or many processes separated by a space :

```bat
@echo off
Title Process Killer by Hackoo 2017
Mode 80,5 & color 0B
Set "TmpFile=%Temp%\TmpFile.txt"
Set "Result=%Temp%\KillResult.txt"
If Exist "%TmpFile%" Del "%TmpFile%"
If Exist "%Resultat%" Del "%Resultat%"
echo(
echo     Enter the process name or processes names separated by a space
echo(
set /p "process=What process(es) do you want to kill ? > "
cls & color 0C
Title Killing "%process%" ...
echo(
echo %date% *** %time% >"%TmpFile%"
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a
Cmd /U /C Type "%TmpFile%" >"%Result%"
Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul
Start "" "%Result%"
::*********************************************************************************************
:KillMyProcess
Set "Process=%~1"
echo                 Killing "%process%" ...
echo "%Process%" | find /I ".exe" >nul 2>&1  && (
    Taskkill /IM "%Process%" /F >>"%TmpFile%" 2>&1
) || (
    Taskkill /IM "%~n1.exe" /F >>"%TmpFile%" 2>&1
)
echo *****************************************************************************>>"%TmpFile%"
exit /b
::**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: If this solution answer your question, you should accept it !